# Is it possible to play a PSP Game brought from the Playstation Store on a PSP Emulator?

Tags: emulation, psp

So i've been looking into how i can go about ripping all my PSP Games for when i am unable to play any of my PSPs (i know it's going to happen) and while 99% of my collection is physical i have 2 games which aren't which i doubt from my UK PSN Account. *God Eater Burst* and *Black Rock Shooter: The Game*

Now *God Eater Burst* has been re-released on newer systems so i don't really need to worry about it, however *Black Rock Shooter: The Game* hasn't and it was never localized in the west with a physical edition.

However, since i brought and downloaded *Black Rock Shooter: The Game* on my PS3 it requires me to copy it onto a Memory Stick Duo so i was wondering, if i copied the game onto the PC would it work on any Emulator (i'm currently using PPSSPP)? do i need to do anything to it first before i can get it to work? or is it just impossible?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ISO or CUE version of this game then you can run it on PPSSPP.
At this moment, it's the best emulator. I can recommend it for you.

Comment: so are you saying that PSP titles brought and downloaded from the playstation store are either of those formats?

Comment: 1.Your PSP must have Custom Firmware (CFW)  2.Press the SELECT button  3. A menu titled VSH menu will appear 4. Go to USB device and choose UMD 5. Connect to the computer with USB cable 6. Open your usual PSP folder in 'My Computer'. You should see a ISO file titled 'UMD9660'